# How would I have a dynamic Activity based on Web Service input?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity

I'm looking to have an app that calls a web service, and the return from that WS would specify a specific puzzle to play (sudoku, arithmetic, logic, problem solving, memory, etc).

I think that each puzzle should be its own Activity, but I don't know if they should be nested in my main app Activity, separate Activities, or something else.

At some point I'd like these puzzle activities to include OpenGL graphics, but for now just simple layout driven Activities should suit me well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that each puzzle should be its
>   own Activity, but I don't know if they
>   should be nested in my main app
>   Activity, separate Activities, or
>   something else.

I would vote for separate activities.

Comment: Is there any performance reason for separate activities?  Or is this more for a cleanliness in architecture approach?

Comment: I will argue it is better for memory management to have a set of smaller activities than one big honking one.